# Configure a Sendmail subject using crontab

Tags: linux, centos, cron, sendmail

My cron job is running the following line:

```
*/40 * * * * cd /home/qa/prod/seo/casino &&  make testv   2> /dev/stdout | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t xxxx@gmail.com
```

As you can see I am using the sendmail package. The thing I don't manage to find out is how to add a subject to the currently-running cron schedule.

I've came across the following :

```
echo "Subject: Testing" | cat - /home/file1.out | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t xxxx@gmail.com
```

However, I have no idea whats the 'cat - /home/file1.out' pipeline does in this case, or how I can integrate it with my own.

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

`cat - /home/file1.out` is for the body of the message.

`-` means STDIN in this case, STDIN for cat.

```
[sgeorge@sgeorge-ld ~]$ echo "Subject: Testing" | cat - file 
Subject: Testing
TESTING TESTING
[sgeorge@sgeorge-ld ~]$ echo "Subject: Testing" | cat file 
TESTING TESTING
```

Actually you don't need it actually:

```
[sgeorge@sgeorge-ld ~]$ cat test 
Subject: Testing
TESTING TESTING
[sgeorge@sgeorge-ld ~]$ cat test | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t xxxxx@xxxxxx.com
```

The just above method will also work in the same way as below one works

```
echo "Subject: Testing" | cat file | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t xxxxx@xxxxxxxx.com
```

**For more understanding:**

```
[sgeorge@sgeorge-ld ~]$ echo "Subject: Testing" | cat file -
TESTING TESTING
Subject: Testing
[sgeorge@sgeorge-ld ~]$ echo "Subject: Testing" | cat - file 
Subject: Testing
TESTING TESTING
```

So `-` is just an `STDIN` here.

Answer (score 1):

The `-` in `cat -` tells cat to read the content from pipeline and print it to stdout, so that `echo "Subject:Testing " | cat - /home/files1.out` means combine "Subject: Testing" with content of files1.out.